# Sequence with stopping values

Tags: r, indexing

This is like a regular tribonacci sequence, however, I want the sequence to stop whenever the term is at the min or max value.

*This is what I have started*

```
sequence <- function(a1=0, a2=0, a3=1, min=0, max=30) {
  an <- c()
  a[1] <- a1
  a[2] <- a2
  a[3] <- a3
  while(a <= max || a >= min) {
    a[i] <- a[i-1] + a[i-2] + a[i-3]
    an <- c(an, a[i])
  }
  an
}
```

Are there any suggestions regarding my code setup, and how to fix the indexing?

Comment: You want to "stop whenever the term is at or exceeds the minimum or maximum value," would eliminate everything after the minimum point so nothing except values before the minimum? What is the point of the maximum value?

Comment: a is always greater than min. So it will run forever. Just use the condition `a <=max`

Comment: @dcarlson @onyambu The point of the max and min is so when the next term in the sequence is at that value or above/below, the sequence stops. ie, `tribonacci(a1=0, a2=0, a3=1, min=0, max=24)` would output
 `0  0  1  1  2  4  7 13 24`                                                                                                                                   The min value can be useful because the user can also plug in a negative value(s) for the starting points. ie `tribonacci(a1=0, a2=1, a3=-3, min=-30, max=1)` would output `0   1  -3  -2  -4  -9 -15 -28`

Comment: I understand now. See the revised answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of coding this using `abs()`:

```
tribonacci <- function(start=c(0, 0, 1), maxval=15) {
    a <- start
    i <- 3
    while(abs(a[i]) <= maxval) {
        i <- i + 1
        a[i] <- a[i-3] + a[i-2] + a[i-1]
    }
    a[1:(i-1)]
}

tribonacci(maxval=24)
# [1]  0  0  1  1  2  4  7 13 24
tribonacci(start=c(0, 1, -3), maxval=30)
# [1]   0   1  -3  -2  -4  -9 -15 -28
```

Since we use the absolute value, we just need one argument to specify the maximum/minimum.